# How do I synchronize data between an editable ListCtrl and a data source?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm trying to build a prototype application that consists of a table
of data linked to a graph, which will be displayed alongside the table
and updated as the data changes.

For the table I'm using a ListCtrl-derived object and, because I want
to be able to edit the data in-place, I'm also inheriting the
TextEditMixin class:

```
class EditableListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, listmix.TextEditMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
             size=wx.DefaultSize, style=0):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, ID, pos, size, style)
    listmix.TextEditMixin.__init__(self)
```

I want to keep my back-end data separate from its display, so my
`wx.Frame`-derived object has a data source object from which it reads
data to populate the ListCtrl.

```
    self.list = EditableListCtrl(panel, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
    self.list.InsertColumn(0, 'A', width=140)
    self.list.InsertColumn(1, 'B', width=130)

    for i in range(0, self.db.getNumRecords()):
        item = self.db.getRecord(i)
        index = self.list.InsertStringItem(sys.maxint, str(item[0]))
        self.list.SetStringItem(index, 1, str(item[1]))
```

Since I now essentially have two copies of the data, I'd like to make
sure that the data source is updated whenever the ListCtrl is
edited by the user.

Is there a standard way to do this?

I have tried binding to the EVT_LIST_ITEM_DESELECTED event, but it
triggers before the TextEditMixin functionality changes the data in
the ListCtrl - the data retrieved from the ListCtrl by the callback
function is the old data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to synchronise the data.

**1. Use a Virtual ListCtrl**

When using a Virtual ListCtrl, you don't have to add data manually. It
pulls data from your data source.

To make a ListCtrl virtual, initialise the ListCtrl with the
`wx.LC_VIRTUAL` style flag.

For the Virtual ListCtrl to pull the data, you need to override the
following functions (obviously you need to subclass ListCtrl first):

```
OnGetItemText(self, item, column)
OnGetItemAttr(self, item)
OnGetItemImage(self, item)
```

The first of these handles string data. I haven't used the other
two. (If you're not using them, just return `None` and `-1` respectively.)

You also need to call `SetItemCount(item_count)` to tell the ListCtrl
how many records to retrieve.

To update the data source when the user modifies a cell, you need to
implement `SetVirtualData(self, row, col, text)`.

See the presentation ["Advanced wxPython Nuts and Bolts" by Robin Dunn](http://wxpython.org/OSCON2008/wxPython-Advanced-OSCON2008.pdf) for more information.

**2. Use a regular ListCtrl**

Subclass ListCtrl and override the function `SetStringItem(self, row,
col, text)`. In your new implementation, update your data source. Don't
forget to also call the base class `SetStringItem()` though! Otherwise,
the ListCtrl appearance won't change.

Virtual ListCtrl is a bit more work, but recommended because you no longer end up with two copies of the data.

*(Thanks to Mike Driscoll for pointing me in the right direction to find this information!)*

Answer (score 3):

There is a way around this apparent anomaly, where you edit the data and yet it appears that you cannot access it, to perform a database update for example.
You need to bind the event to the listctrl and then access event.GetLabel not listCtrl.GetText
for example:

```
self.listCtrl.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_END_LABEL_EDIT, self.OnMixUpdate)
```

and then:

```
def OnMixUpdate(self, event):
    # Set the changed data via the event.GetLabel not listCtrl.GetText which remains unchanged until we change it
    rowid = self.listCtrl.GetFocusedItem ()
    new_data = event.GetLabel ()
    colid = event.GetColumn ()
    self.listCtrl.SetStringItem(rowid,colid,new_data,)
    #Update a textctrl on screen
    self.SetData()
    #Update database
    self.OnUpdate(None)
    event.Skip()
```

The above is using a normal listctrl()
This particular problem drove me nuts for more than day before I came up with this solution. I suspect that there are others but I couldn't find one. In fact based my web searches it doesn't appear that more than a handful of people have come across this problem.

You can replace the line
    rowid = self.listCtrl.GetFocusedItem ()
with
    rowid = event.GetIndex()
and get the same result which perhaps reads better

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it. How do you have two copies of the data? One in the database and one on display? That's always going to be the case. When it comes to something like this, I think the usual method I've seen advertised is to use a Virtual ListCtrl (see the wxPython demo).

You can also look at how I did it with MediaLocker:

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/12/09/ann-medialocker-%E2%80%93-a-wxpython-app-to-track-your-media/

Or in my original app that was the basis for MediaLocker:

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/11/10/wxpython-and-sqlalchemy-an-intro-to-mvc-and-crud/

I'm using ObjectListView instead of the ListCtrl as I find it easier to use.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not complaining that there's two copies of the data. I'm just surprised there isn't an event I can bind to which activates when data in the ListCtrl changes. Otherwise, what's the point of being able to edit it? Do I have to poll the ListCtrl? I'll have a look at the Virtual ListCtrl and ObjectListView though and see if they are any better.

Comment: I didn't know StackOverflow allowed users to ask AND answer their own questions, not to mention accept their own answers.

Comment: It does, but you don't get any rep for it.

Answer (score 1):

The event you're looking for is `wx.EVT_LIST_END_LABEL_EDIT`, I think.